# .htaccess redirect rule only root-domain

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying a regex for my .htaccess redirect rule that only much if the domain has no directories:

domain.ch -> rule has to match

domain.ch/some/director -> rule should **not match**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.ch [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.ch/fr/goto/ [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: `^$` - pattern anchored at the start _and_ end, to force a match only of the path component of the URL is completely empty.

Comment: thanks, do you mean like so: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} $^(www\.)?ragusa.ch$ [NC]

unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: It should be `RewriteRule ^$`

Comment: No, I meant in the RewriteRule, that's the one matching against the URL path.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ https://....` - Do you know what the `^` (first argument) in your `RewriteRule` directive does? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule